# How to determine a good initial size for SQL Transaction LOG file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We run SQL Server 2008 R2. The database sizes vary from 20-500 gb, and are all in full recovery mode.

I find it hard to determine a good initial size for the transaction log files, to prevent autogrowth's. It depends on multipele factors, but can anyone give some rule of thumb on a good value for the initial size of the log? Can I see how fast a log is growing in the last xx time or something?

Any advice on this subject is very welcome.. thanks!

Comment: What information do you have? Has the database been in production for some time? What'S the log configuration right now?

Comment: The bigger databases are in production for several years. The log config is differens per database, thats why I want to make it a bit more consistent, and am I looking for good initial sizes. (one log is 200gb, another is 25, there is no good line in it right now).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to collect metadata over a period of time to understand the growth pattern of your logfiles. The query below can be set up as a job, to fetch and populate a table with the metadata and then you will be able to understand what your initial size will need to be

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS DateRun 
     ,(size * 8.0)/1024.0 AS size_in_mb
     , CASE
  WHEN max_size                                 = -1 
  THEN 9999999                  -- Unlimited growth, so handle this how you want
  ELSE (max_size * 8.0)/1024.0                  END AS max_size_in_mb
  FROM YOURDBNAMEHERE.sys.database_files
 WHERE data_space_id                            = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid auto-grow because it can introduce latency and load spikes. Small auto-grow increments will also cause VLF fragmentation. Still, auto-grow should be enabled as a safety net.

The goal is to have it on, but never kick in in practice. Second-level goal is to not waste space and have quick recovery times. Logs cannot be instant-initialized.

When I size a log I size it so that the chance of an auto-grow event during normal operations is low. If I was forced to quantify that, I'd say that 10% chance per year is a pretty safe standard. I set the grow increment to a low value to avoid latency spiked (even timeouts) in case an auto-grow is required.

Determine, how much log space is being generated at most between two log backups. Probably, you want to measure the growth rate per hour at peak load and add a safety margin. You can very crudely measure the growth rate by taking note of the allocated space in the log file(s) one hour apart.

Some maintenance operations can also very quickly generate tons of log. You need to measure this as well.

The key is to measure peak log generation between two log backups according to your backup schedule.

If you want a quicker, less scientific solution: Start with a small log, let it auto-grow by a rather small increment (256MB?) and look how big it got after a week. Then "reformat" the log to remove VLF fragmentation (shrink, then set the final size plus safety margin).